# MATLAB null conditional operator

Tags: matlab

All

I'm interested in MATLAB null conditional operator or something very similar.

Suppose I have logger in MATLAB class/methods but want to use this class in another small project, where no logger is set up.

In C# I would code would look like

```
logger?.warn('WARNING');

...

logger?.debug('Three is 3');
```

and if external code sets logger to null, no calls would be made. So code continues to work just fine, like no logger is present. This is called null conditional operator.

Is there a similar idiom for MATLAB? How it could be done in most simple and elegant way?

Our logger is a singleton wrapping around log4j java class

Comment: How does your logger work? Is it a function you call? Or a global variable?

Comment: @CrisLuengo No, this is an object I got from singleton, and then bunch of methods logger.warn(), logger.debug(), logger.error() etc. Would be nice if I could leave code with logger calls, but they would do nothing

Comment: I’m asking because I imagine the way to do this would be to have an alternative implementation that does nothing, that you package with your application, and that would be used only if the logger is not present when running. But proposing this as a solution requires knowing how the logger is set up.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to **implement something analogous to your `?.` operator**, such as this function I've called `evalif`. This lets you do calls without creating any additional classes, and is fairly flexible to get this behaviour in multiple situations.

```
function evalif( obj, f, varargin )
    if isempty(obj)
        % If obj is empty [] then just exit here
        return
    end
    if ismethod( obj, f )
        % Additional check that this is a valid method of the object before
        % running it. If it is then run it, passing through all inputs
        obj.(f)( varargin{:} )
    else
        error( '"%s" is not a valid method for object of class "%s"', f, class(obj) );
    end
end
```

If you call it pointing to some empty object, i.e. `[]` then nothing will happen. Otherwise you can ask to call one of the (valid) methods of a given object using the dynamic `obj.(f)` syntax. Note that the execution time will likely be a little slower that doing this explicitly, although for logging that likely doesn't matter.

**An alternative** would be to create a `NullLogger` class which mimics the available methods of the `Logger` class, but they all do nothing. Then you can set your `logger = NullLogger();` and you don't have to modify existing code, just create a specific null version off the class. Note you now have to maintain this class to emulate functionality of the `Logger` class. You might be able to inherit from the `Logger` as a base class and just overwrite specific functions to make this potentially easier.

Some test cases with both the simple `Logger` and `NullLogger` classes:

```
>> logger = Logger();
>> evalif( [], 'warn', 'this' )
>> evalif( logger, 'warn', 'this' )
WARNING: this
>> evalif( logger, 'foo', 'this' )
Error using evalif (line 12)
"foo" is not a valid method for object of class "Logger"

>> logger = NullLogger();
>> logger.warn( 'test' )
>> logger = Logger();
>> logger.warn( 'test' )
WARNING: test
```

The logger and null logger:

```
classdef Logger
    methods (Static)
        function warn( str )
            fprintf( 'WARNING: %s\n', str );
        end
        function debug( str )
            fprinf( 'DEBUG: %s\n', str );
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef NullLogger
    methods (Static)
        function warn( str )     
            % Do nothing
        end
        function debug( str )
            % Do nothing
        end
    end
end
```